How to Dynamically Tune the Number of Layers in a Neural Network Using mlr3torch?
I’m building a neural network with a tunable number of layers. While I can successfully tune the number of neurons per layer, I’m encountering issues when it comes to dynamically changing the number of layers.
Initially, I thought I could handle this using po("nn_block"). However, after reading the documentation, I realized that nn_block is more suited for repeating a segment of the network multiple times. My goal is to be able to tune the number of layers, from 1 to a maximum value, while maintaining the ability to tune the number of neurons in each layer.
Here’s a minimal reproducible example that demonstrates my current approach:
# Load necessary libraries
if (!require("pacman")) install.packages("pacman")
pacman::p_load(
  future,
  future.apply,
  magrittr,
  mlr3hyperband,
  mlr3torch,
  mlr3tuning,
  mlr3verse,
  tidyverse,
  install = TRUE
)

torch::install_torch()

# Set seed for reproducibility
seed = 2024
set.seed(seed)

# Use built-in iris dataset for simplicity
tab <- iris
colnames(tab)[which(names(tab) == "Species")] <- "target"
tab$target <- as.factor(tab$target)

# Initialize classification task
task <- TaskClassif$new(id = "iris", backend = tab, target = "target")

# Function to generate neural network layers with tunable parameters
generate_layers <- function(max_layers) {
  layers <- list()
  for (i in 1:max_layers) {
    layers[[i]] <- po("nn_linear", out_features = to_tune(p_int(32, 512)), id = paste0("linear_", i)) %>>%
      po("nn_dropout", p = to_tune(p_dbl(0.3, 0.5)), id = paste0("dropout_", i)) %>>%
      po("nn_relu", id = paste0("relu_", i))
  }
  return(layers)
}

# Create a list of layers
max_layers <- 5
layers <- generate_layers(max_layers)

# Concatenate the layers into the neural network architecture
architecture <- po("torch_ingress_num")
for (i in 1:max_layers) {
  architecture <- architecture %>>% layers[[i]]
}

# Add head, loss, optimizer, and configurations to the architecture
architecture <- architecture %>>%
  po("nn_head") %>>%
  po("torch_loss", t_loss("cross_entropy")) %>>%
  po("torch_optimizer", t_opt("adam", lr = to_tune(p_dbl(0.001, 0.01)))) %>>%
  po("torch_model_classif", batch_size = 32, epochs = to_tune(p_int(100, 1000, tags = "budget")), device = "cpu", num_threads = 1)

# Convert the architecture to a learner object
learner <- as_learner(architecture)
learner$id <- "iris"
learner$predict_type <- "prob"
learner$param_set$values$torch_model_classif.seed <- seed

# Define the tuning terminator and instance for optimization
terminator <- trm("evals", n_evals = 100)
resampling <- rsmp("cv", folds = 5)

instance <- ti(
  task = task, learner = learner, resampling = resampling,
  measure = msr("classif.bacc"), terminator = terminator
)

# Optimize using Hyperband tuner
tuner <- tnr("hyperband", eta = 3, repetitions = 1)
num_threads = 8
future::plan(multisession, workers = num_threads)
tuner$optimize(instance)

The above code works well in terms of tuning the number of neurons and the learning rate, but I'm stuck when trying to make the number of layers tunable.
How to adjust the number of layers dynamically in mlr3torch?
